# How to iterate through list in number of elements at once?

Tags: python

For example, I have simple list like this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to iterate over it in groups of 3 elements:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

What is simplest way to do it?

Comment: IMO the best way to do this is described here, and is adapted from a recipe in the `itertools` documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/434411/2073595.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tricky, but well-known way (from [`itertools` grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)):

```
>>> zip(*[iter(l)] * 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

It can be written as

```
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> zip(it, it, it)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Full explanation here: [How does zip(*[iter(s)]*n) work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: That's nice. Could you give one or two sentences what is happening here.

Comment: Careful though.  Since `zip` truncates to the shortest of the sequences, if `l` isn't divisible by `3` exactly, you'll lose a couple trailing elements.  That's why the grouper recipe uses `izip_longest`.  Just for fun, a couple days ago, on a duplicate question to this, [I wrote up a whole bunch of different ways to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23926929/748858) each with _slightly_ different output and different input assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

result = [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(l),3)]

>>> print result
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> for i in result:
...     print(i)
... 
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write simple generator

```
def group_gen(lst, n):
    for i in range(0,len(lst), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]


for a,b,c in group_gen(l, 3):
    print(a,b,c)
```

Results in:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```