# python process list elements in batches

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have sequence of played cards in a list. There were 4 players, so each four elements in the list represent a single trick. I have to process 4 cards together to find trick winner. I need to split the list four elements at a time. I am currently doing the following:

```
cardSequnce = [
    'D7', 'D8', 'DT', 'DA',
    'H2', 'H7', 'HK', 'H5',
    'H3', 'HT', 'HA', 'HQ',
    'H8', 'D2', 'H4', 'HJ',
    'D6', 'D3'
]
four_card = []
for index, card in enumerate(cardSequnce):
    if(index % 4 == 0):
        # process four_card
        four_card = []
    four_card.append(card)
```

I think that I can do better than this using power of python. Can I access 4 cards together in a loop? Can any one help me to make my code more Pythonic?

Comment: Try the `grouper` recipe from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to create lists of length of 4 from a list, this would do the trick:

```
[cardSequence[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(cardSequence), 4)]
```

Comment: this has been tagged with Python 3, change `xrange` to just `range`.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I didn't pay attention to tags.

Comment: Thanks, It helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
offset = 4
index = 0
while index < len(YourList):
       result = YourList[index:index+offset]
       index += offset
```

Comment: This is definitely much less Pythonic than using `range` in a `for` loop, but probably still better than OP's original solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code a bit nicer by iterating explicitly through groups of four instead of element-by-element. There are a couple of ways of doing this. The easiest would just be to increment the index by four:

```
card_sequence = ...
for index in range(0, len(cardSequence), 4):
    four_card = card_sequence[index:index + 4]
    # process four_card
```

This has the advantage of not calling the processing code on an empty `four_card` when `index == 0`, as your code does. Also, I would recommend sticking to one naming convention (underscores vs CamelCase). I picked the former since that is the generally recommended Python convention.

You can do a slightly more complicated version using the `grouper` recipe provided by the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). The advantage of this approach is that it will probably scale better:

> ```
> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
>     "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
>     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
>     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
>     return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
> ```

```
card_sequence = ...
for four_card in grouper(card_sequence, 4):
    four_card = list(four_card)
    # Process four_card
```

Keep in mind that this implementation of `grouper` is going to fill extra elements in the last group with `None` if your input sequence does not have a multiple of four elements. It also assumes that you consume all the elements of the group in each iteration (which you do in this case). For alternative implementations, see [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23926929/2988730).